# Error al instanciar un objeto de una clase en QT Creator C++

Tags: c++, qt-creator

Necesito crear un método `AgregarProyecto`, que permite agregar en un lista un nuevo proyecto.

Mi problema es el siguiente: Al querer hacer una instancia de la clase `proyecto`, que recibe 3 argumentos, me tira el siguiente error:

> error: conversion from 'proyecto*' to non-scalar type 'proyecto'
>   requested
>        proyecto unProyecto = new proyecto(nombre,descripcion,directorio);

El método es el siguiente:

```
void MainWindow::agregarProyecto(QString nombre, QString descripcion, QString directorio)`{`
    proyecto unProyecto = new proyecto (nombre,descripcion,directorio);
    this->listaProyectos.append(unProyecto);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
proyecto unProyecto = new proyecto (nombre,descripcion,directorio);
```

`unProyecto` debería ser un puntero:

```
proyecto* unProyecto = new proyecto (nombre,descripcion,directorio);
//      ^ AQUI!!!
```

Comment: Por que debería ser un puntero? No logro entender porque cada vez que se realiza una instancia a un objeto se debe anteponer *. Soy nuevo en c++.

Comment: @marcosvasquez `new` se usa para trabajar con memoria dinámica. Los punteros se usan para acceder a objetos ubicados en posiciones aleatorias de memoria. En cualquier caso si eres nuevo en C++ te aconsejo dejar Qt por el momento y aprender los fundamentos de C++

Answer (score 0):

Un puntero de la clase `Foo` se declara e inicia de la siguiente forma:

```
Foo* myObjeto = new Foo (...);
```

Lo que falta es el operador de punteros `*`.